# Inadvertantly Shifting Plots in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've got some weird behaviour in matplotlib that I couldn't explain, and I was wondering if someone could see what was going on.  What's essentially happening is that I'm trying to place what used to be two figures into one.  I do so by creating two `GridSpec` objects, one for the left half of the figure and the other for the right.  I draw the left hand side and add a `colorbar`, but when I select my first `subplot` on the right hand side, the figure on the left shifts to the right *under* the colorbar. If you try executing the example code excluding the last two lines, you will see what you expect, but if you execute the entirety of it, the plot on the left shifts.  What's going on?

```
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
import numpy as np
import pylab as pl

scores = np.array([[ 0.32      ,  0.32      ,  0.32      ,  0.32      ,  0.32      ,
         0.32      ,  0.32      ,  0.32      ,  0.32      ],
       [ 0.32      ,  0.32      ,  0.32      ,  0.49333333,  0.85333333,
         0.92666667,  0.32      ,  0.32      ,  0.32      ],
       [ 0.32      ,  0.32      ,  0.51333333,  0.87333333,  0.96      ,
         0.95333333,  0.89333333,  0.44      ,  0.34      ],
       [ 0.32      ,  0.51333333,  0.88      ,  0.96      ,  0.96666667,
         0.95333333,  0.90666667,  0.47333333,  0.34      ],
       [ 0.51333333,  0.88      ,  0.96      ,  0.96      ,  0.96      ,
         0.96      ,  0.90666667,  0.47333333,  0.34      ],
       [ 0.88      ,  0.96      ,  0.96      ,  0.96      ,  0.94666667,
         0.96      ,  0.90666667,  0.47333333,  0.34      ],
       [ 0.96      ,  0.96      ,  0.96666667,  0.96      ,  0.94      ,
         0.96      ,  0.90666667,  0.47333333,  0.34      ],
       [ 0.96      ,  0.96666667,  0.96666667,  0.94666667,  0.94      ,
         0.96      ,  0.90666667,  0.47333333,  0.34      ],
       [ 0.96666667,  0.97333333,  0.96      ,  0.94666667,  0.94      ,
         0.96      ,  0.90666667,  0.47333333,  0.34      ],
       [ 0.96666667,  0.96666667,  0.96666667,  0.94666667,  0.94      ,
         0.96      ,  0.90666667,  0.47333333,  0.34      ],
       [ 0.95333333,  0.96      ,  0.96666667,  0.94666667,  0.94      ,
         0.96      ,  0.90666667,  0.47333333,  0.34      ]])
C_range = 10.0 ** np.arange(-2, 9)
gamma_range = 10.0 ** np.arange(-5, 4)

pl.figure(0, figsize=(16,6))
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(1,1)
gs.update(left=0.05, right=0.45, bottom=0.15, top=0.95)
pl.subplot(gs[0,0])
pl.imshow(scores, interpolation='nearest', cmap=pl.cm.spectral)
pl.xlabel('gamma')
pl.ylabel('C')
pl.colorbar()
pl.xticks(np.arange(len(gamma_range)), gamma_range, rotation=45)
pl.yticks(np.arange(len(C_range)), C_range)
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(3,3)
gs.update(left=0.5, right=0.95, bottom=0.05, top=0.95)
pl.subplot(gs[0,0])  # here's where the shift happens
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the colorbar after # here's where the shift happens

```
pl.figure(0, figsize=(16,6))
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(1,1)
gs.update(left=0.05, right=0.45, bottom=0.15, top=0.95)
ax = pl.subplot(gs[0,0])  # save the axes to ax
pl.imshow(scores, interpolation='nearest', cmap=pl.cm.spectral)
pl.xlabel('gamma')
pl.ylabel('C')
pl.xticks(np.arange(len(gamma_range)), gamma_range, rotation=45)
pl.yticks(np.arange(len(C_range)), C_range)
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(3,3)
gs.update(left=0.5, right=0.95, bottom=0.05, top=0.95)
pl.subplot(gs[0,0])  # here's where the shift happens

pl.colorbar(ax=ax) # create colorbar for ax
pl.show()
```

[image]